# Python-Opencv Watershed markers

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to create a web based foreground extraction service (similar to [clippingmagic.com](http://clippingmagic.com)).

I am using marker based watershed image segmentation (opencv, python).
I am using sketch.js for allowing users to draw the markers on the image.

I need to call the python script from my php code.
Here's what the script needs to do:

1. Read the image which has the markers drawn on it.
2. Create a matrix of integers where different colored markers are labelled with different integers.
3. Feed the markers matrix and input image to the watershed algorithm and store the output to a local file.
4. Extract the foreground which is marked with the corresponding marker.
5. Display the output to the user.

I am facing problem with step 2.

Here is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import cv2
from common import Sketcher

img_m = cv2.imread('1_m.jpg'); //my image which has colored marks on it

h, w = img.shape[:2]
markers = np.zeros((h, w), np.int32)

cv2.imshow("Image",img_m);

//trying to put '1' at all places where image is marked with color (179,230,29)
markers = np.where((img_m == [179,230,29]),1,0)
//trying to put '2' at all places where image is marked with color (238,27,34)
markers = np.where((img_m == [238,27,34]),2,0)

cv2.watershed(img, markers) //gives me error "markers should be 1-channel 32-bit image"

cv2.waitKey(50)
```

Can somebody help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: I think shape for the `np.zeros` needs to be `(h, w, 1)`.

Comment: @Igonato It didnt help.
The 'markers' matrix is correctly initialized to 32-bit single channel.
The problem is at "markers = np.where((img_m == [179,230,29]),1,0)"
after which the 'markers' matrix turns to 3-channel instead of 1.

Comment: Right. You are redefining your `markers` variable here. Try using something else to set markers values. I'd go with the `map` function or simple loop just to check that watershed is working, then search for a clever numpy way to do this.

Comment: @Igonato Tried a nested loop. Works like a charm.
But haven't found a numpy aka faster way of doing it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I played with the `array[array==[b, r, g]] = x` expression in the interactive mode, it doesn't work as expected, alongside with needed triplets it returns some junk and i am not sure what is wrong. It's pretty easy to write a C extension for this type of task, but that is one of the last thing to do since it can create more problems.

Comment: How do you get the markers values? Maybe you can get them somewhere before in your app? And keep it separate from the processing image?

Comment: why not "GrabCut" in OpenCV3?